# Antes de un infinitivo, ¿son correctas todas las opciones "intento de", "intento por" e "intento para"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Decir "intento de", "intento por" e "intento para" antes de un infinitivo, ¿son todos correctos o es preferible uno de ellos?

He comprobado el DLE y el Nuevo Manual de Gramática, pero sigue confundiéndome.

He encontrado los tres en publicaciones reconocidas:

Ejemplos de "intento de":

- [KPMG asesorará Nissan en **el intento de salvar** las plantas de Barcelona](https://cincodias.elpais.com/cincodias/2021/01/25/companias/1611604821_617248.html)
- [El sueco Armand Duplantis falló tres veces ante la barra de 6,19 metros, en **su intento de mejorar** su propia plusmarca (6,18 metros, conseguida en 2020) en el salto con garrocha.](https://www.eluniversal.com/deportes/100684/karsten-warholm-bate-el-record-mundial-de-los-400-metros-con-vallas)
- [El intento de mediación del pasado día 18, por parte de la Dirección General de Trabajo, no fructificó y se trata de **un último intento de evitar** la huelga fijada para el miércoles y el jueves.](https://cincodias.elpais.com/cincodias/2018/07/23/companias/1532371287_501121.html)

Ejemplos de "intento por":

- [Asimismo, se han llevado a cabo eventos más pequeños en lugares de la ciudad en **un intento por vacunar** a tantos londinenses como ha sido posible…](https://www.elmundo.es/ciencia-y-salud/salud/2021/06/20/60ced1f4e4d4d8967f8b457a.html)
- [El encuentro se perfila como **un intento por dejar atrás** la época en que Donald Trump ejercía la presidencia en Estados Unidos y Benjamin Netanyahu gobernaba Israel…](https://www.eluniversal.com.co/mundo/enviados-de-ee-uu-e-israel-se-reunen-en-roma-DL4863588)
- [Otro de **los intentos por salvar** a Venecia llegó hace apenas unas semanas…](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/turismo/venecia-y-amsteredam-frente-al-dilema-de-alejar-a-los-visitantes-nid30052021/)

Ejemplos de "intento para"

- [Google hace **un nuevo intento para competir** con Facebook en el terreno de la red social.](https://elpais.com/tecnologia/2011/06/29/actualidad/1309338062_850215.html)
- [El Gobierno emprendió ayer **un tercer intento para construir** la nueva carretera San José-Caldera…](https://www.nacion.com/el-pais/nuevo-intento-para-construir-carretera-san-jose-caldera/5QZSRLEQE5DWZPEY23TKDEOL2I/story/)

Parece que "intento de" siempre se utiliza  antes de un sustantivo, pero ¿hay alguna regla para los casos en que aparece antes de un infinitivo?

Comment: No veo como pueda haber una regla para de, por y para con un substantivo en si. de, por y para se utlizan para diferentes metas.

Comment: No encuentro demasiada diferencia de significado entre las tres, excepto que "intento para" suena bastante rara. - "intento de" es la única frase que puede preceder a un sustantivo además de un infinitivo. Tal vez por eso aparece con una frecuencia de uso muy superior a las otras dos. - "intento por" le sigue en frecuencia de uso. - "intento para" es definitivamente la menos usada de las tres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En 'Intento DE+inf/sustantivo' DE es la más usada, pero no me agrega ningún matiz.

Creo que hay que diferenciar primero lo que es **intento** como una **acción real reiterativa** a/de cuando se quiere expresar algo que se quiere lograr, como un **propósito**.

P.ej en 'falla en su intento de ver' si se quiere expresar propósito no se debería escribir 'in his/her attempt' basta con 'he/she failed to look for' porque 'to' indica objetivo 'con el fin de', es como decir simplemente 'no logró ver'.

En los ejemplos que se proporcionaron:

- ...y se trata de UN último intento DE evitar la huelga...

Acá diría DEL si se quiere enfatizar que es 'el último', con UN deja abierta la posibilidad de que haya otros más:

- ...y se trata DEL último intento PARA evitar la huelga...

Acá no es redundante porque es una acción reiterativa, hubieron otras reuniones, es un hecho real.

- KPMG asesorará a Nissan en EL intento DE salvar las plantas de Barcelona

Si quiero decir que KPMG solo proporciona la parte técnica diría en su lugar:

- KPMG asesorará a Nissan en SU intento DE salvar las plantas de Barcelona.

'En su intento de' es similar a 'con el objetivo/fin de' por lo tanto lo omito porque de lo contrario sería redundante(porque es el propósito global, no algo que depende de un intento en particular), mejor decir:

- KPMG asesorará a Nissan PARA salvar las plantas de Barcelona.

No obstante es evidente que se utiliza PARA también por influencia del inglés o por lo que sea.

- intento para explicar = explain why
- intento para evitar = attempt to avoid
- intento para construir = attempt to build
- etc

'POR' también es usado en algunas regiones con el sentido de 'DE' sin más:

- intento de/por integrar = attempt to integrate
- intento de/por encontrar = attempt to find
- intento de/por (la) unificación = attempt to unify
- etc

También podría significar con 'POR' que es más imperiosa la necesidad de alcanzar el resultado, esto es sólo una suposición basada en la frecuencia y en textos que tienen relación con cálculos matemáticos.

- intento por mantener = effort to keep
- intento por limitar = attempt to achieve
- intento por recomponer = attempts to recompose
- intento por implementar = effort to implement
- intento por parecer = attempt to be
- intento por llegar = attempt to get
- etc

En este ejemplo también se podría confundir si se toma POR como un intercambio:

- KPMG asesorará a Nissan en el intento POR salvar las plantas de Barcelona.

Lo cual significaría:

- KPMG asesorará a Nissan A CAMBIO DE salvar las plantas de Barcelona.

Pero POR no solo se usa para INTERCAMBIO, sino que es uno de sus tantos usos.